# Explain phrase "For each pair of distinct elements" in reference to a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

In one of my algorithm courses, there is this:

> A subset $S$ of vertices in a directed graph $G$ is
>   strongly connected if for each pair of distinct
>   vertices ($v_i$, $v_j$) in $S$, $v_i$ is connected to $v_j$ and
>   $v_j$ is connected to $v_i$.

And then the following example graph is given for this proposition:

[image]

Maybe i do not understand what that phrase means. What i think it means is this: A node, say $E$ can be a member of an ordered pair $(v_i, v_j)$ only once, ie. if $(E, A)$, then $\lnot (E, [someOtherNode]) $. But we clearly see here, that we have $(E,A)$ and $(E,D)$.

How should i correctly interpret this phrase. What does it mean exactly? Thanks.

Comment: *distinct*, I believe, refers not the the pairs but the vertices in the pair.  So this condition would *not* require a vertex to be connected to itself.

Comment: So there can be $(v_1, v_2)$ and $(v_1, v_3)$ and $(v_4, v_1)$, but not $(v_2, v_1)$ because both $v_2$ and $v_1$ have been used already in a pair? That's what i can make of it.

Comment: No.  The definition doesn't require that the *pairs* be distinct.  In the phrase “pair of distinct vertices“, notice that the adjective “distinct” modifies “vertices”.  Jose has it right.

Comment: By the way, I don't think this is a soft question.  It's a good question!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks. Your last comment gave me more clarity. So the vertices should be distinct. hmmm So $(v_1, v_2)$, $(v_2, v_3)$, $(v_3, v_4)$ are valid. Right. What is not valid then to this set, is what i want to know? $(v_1, v_2)$ again obviously is not valid, $(v_2, v_4)$ apparently is valid..

Comment: Maybe I should write an answer then.

Comment: Now that you have some answers, an exercise. Is a subset consisting of zero vertices -- the empty set -- *strongly connected*?  Is a subset consisting of one vertex *strongly connected*? Can you produce formal proofs?

Comment: How does your text define *connected*, not in the usage "$G$ is a connected graph" but in the usage "the vertex $u$ is ***connected to*** the vertex $v?$ Also, please ***identify*** the text (and author) from which you have copied an exercise and a diagram ***without attribution.***

Comment: @bof As vadim123 said in his answer below. I do not know the author. My professor had this as a series of slides for lecture presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your subset $S$ of vertices you can construct a set of pairs $P$, where $(v,w) \in P$ if there is a directed path from $v$ to $w$ (not necessarily confined to $S$).  The set is strongly connected if
$$
    \forall v,w\in S, ( v\neq w \Rightarrow (v,w) \in P \wedge (w,v) \in P)
$$
Let $S=G$ in the example graph.  Notice that $(A,B)$, $(B,C)$, $(C,D)$, $(D,E)$, $(E,A)$ are all in $P$.  So by transitivity, every pair of distinct vertices is in $P$.

The word *distinct* in the definition rules out the requirement that $(v,v) \in P$.  However, it seems that $(v,w) \in P \wedge (w,v) \in P$ would imply that $(v,v)\in P$ anyway.

I'm not sure what you mean by “valid” pair.  Any pair *may* be in $P$; the condition is only that certain pairs *must* be in $P$.

Answer (score 10):

Also, "connected" does not mean by a directed edge, but by a directed [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)).

Comment: Good answer but I'd omit the "Also." It seems to me that the meaning of "connected" is the *main* thing the OP is confused about here.

Comment: @bof, the reason I wrote "also", is that I am not answering the question being asked, as it was in its original form.

Answer (score 9):

I think "for each pair of distinct vertices $(v_i, v_j)$ in $S \times S$" means

> "for each $(v_i, v_j) \in S \times S$, $v_i \neq v_j$."

Comment: I think here $v_i \neq v_j$ and $i \neq j$ are requirements that lead to same sets. In other words $i \neq j$ is redundant.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra, thank you for pointing that out.  I have removed the redundant condition.

Comment: Actually, the indices $i,j$ themselves are superfluous. I'd prefer to see this written as "For each $(v,w)\in S\times S$ with $v\ne w$, we have ..."